# Surrogate Court Petition for Probate NY Notification To Others In WIll

Tags: new-york-state, wills, probate

I am in the process of filing papers with the surrogate court for petition of probate. I am just compiling all the needed information and such before I do so. I was told others named in the will need to be informed and listed.
What is the form called that is sent to the other people named in the will? Also, does a copy of each get submitted at time of submitting the paperwork?

Answer (score 1):

A Notice of Probate, and an Affidavit of Mailing of Notice of Probate. This is part of a [package of standard court forms](https://www.nycourts.gov/LegacyPDFS/FORMS/surrogates/pdfs/ADM.pdf), most of which, including that one, are usually submitted at the same time.

[Parallel forms](https://www.nycourts.gov/LegacyPDFS/FORMS/surrogates/pdfs/ADM.pdf) called a Notice of Application for Letters of Administration and an Affidavit of Mailing of Notice of Application for Letters of Administration are used when there is no will.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So the first link you provided, Package of standard court forms, https://www.nycourts.gov/LegacyPDFS/FORMS/surrogates/pdfs/ADM.pdf, gets submitted along with this ? https://www.nycourts.gov/LegacyPDFS/FORMS/surrogates/pdfs/Probate.pdf

Comment: @explore99 You use the Probate package if there is a will, and there Letters of Administration if there is no will. Probate includes a request of letters of administration as well.

Comment: I truly appreciate the help. There is a will, person named me executor and there is property involved. So the Package Of Standard Court Forms(your original link) is all I need then? Do I still need to submit this one as well, https://www.nycourts.gov/LegacyPDFS/FORMS/surrogates/pdfs/Probate.pdf ,or is the package basically the same?

Comment: How are the other people notified? Is it a form I mail to them before submitting papers to the court and if so, what is it called?

Comment: @explore99 You need only the probate packet. I think that they are the same (but you should check). The notices are sent per the form packet contemporaneously with the submission of the probate application. If you appointed, you send another document called an "information of appointment" (or something similar) to the people the court determines are entitled to notice. Once appointed creditors receive notice as set forth in the probate laws.

Comment: You guys were a huge help but I have another question:  https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/68173/surrogate-court-for-petition-of-probate-new-york-combined-verification-oath-a