# Surrogate Court for Petition of Probate New York - COMBINED VERIFICATION, OATH AND DESIGNATION what is SS

Tags: legal-terms, new-york-state, court, trusts-and-estates, notaries

In NY, when filling out forms for Petition of Probate, it reads the following:
COMBINED VERIFICATION, OATH AND DESIGNATION
[For use when petitioner is an individual]
STATE OF NEW YORK )_______
COUNTY OF _________ ss.________

**What is the ss? Is that social security number of the petitioner or something else?**

Page 5.
https://www.nycourts.gov/LegacyPDFS/FORMS/surrogates/pdfs/Probate.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The "SS" is a standard part of a the notarization language on a document which is known as the "jurat" of a document.

The “SS” stands for the Latin term “scilicet” which means "in particular" or "namely" and simply indicates that the place where the document was signed is described in the preceding bracketed portion of the jurat.

You do not have mark anything or fill in any additional information on the “SS” designation itself. Completing the areas marked "State of ________" and "County of _________" with the location where the notarization takes place is where you enter the necessary information for the venue portion of this form.

You are no doubt confused because one of the possible jurats for the form (the one for an individual petitioner) has a fill in the blank line which I have screen shotted below:

[image]

**The inclusion of a line to fill in following "ss." on the form is a drafting error in the form, which is not repeated in the other jurats on the form, probably because the person who drafted the form didn't know what it meant.**

**Another Flaw In The Form**

The same portion of the form also has another drafting error although a less innocent one and it appears in all of the jurats on that form.

It should have omitted the words "New York" because it is not mandatory to actually notarize the Petition at a location that is physically within the State of New York, even though usually this is what will be done. On the other hand there was a requirement to sign the document in New York State, in contrast (which there isn't) then the fill in the blank line following "New York" should have been omitted.

This is a case of someone gratuitously including an apparent extra-statutory requirement in a form (probably because they often have to reject forms if the state isn't filled in at all), without an explanation that "New York" may be crossed out and replaced with another state in the space following the name of the state.

Comment: Great and thank you again for all your help. I have 2 more questions if I can impose and I think I finally have it complete. I am really trying to make sure I am doing this correct.

Comment: Ask more questions as new OPs if you want. The question you asked this time was entirely legitimate and reasonable and since it applies to anyone using that form which applies to every New York State probate case (and to almost any notarization block you could encounter anywhere), I wouldn't consider this question to be one asking for specific legal advice.

Comment: Great and thank you again for all your help. I have 2 more questions if I can impose and I think I finally have it complete. I am really trying to make sure I am doing this correct.  Page #3 , 9A...To the best of the knowledge of the undersigned, the approximate total value of all property constituting 
the decedent’s gross testamentary estate is greater than $---- but less than $ ----
 Personal Property $----- Improved real property in New York State $----.<br/>Is the GROSS the total of the Personal and real Property that follows it?<br/>(see next comment)

Comment: Page 4, number 10. I'm assuming I check off letters of testamentary and just print and sign name? This I am unsure of......Sorry I dont know what a New OP is, I am struggling using site/learning

Comment: @explore99 You check the box and print your name. "New OP" means that you would normally ask a new question rather than continuing a discussion in an old one.

Comment: "gross testamentary estate" means the total combined fair market value of all assets that are real or personal property of the decedent as of the date of death, without deductions for mortgages, for personal property security interests, for debts or taxes owed by the decedent or for property exempt from creditors. But it does not including assets that pass at death outside the probate process, e.g., financial accounts and life insurance with designated beneficiaries, joint tenancy or tenancy by entireties real estate, property held in a trust, property subject to a transfer on death deed. . .

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/68176/surrogate-court-for-petition-of-probate-new-york-last-will-date-witness

Comment: I've been meaning to research the "ss" thing for years. Thanks for doing it for me.